# Interacting with SVN from appengine

Tags: java, python, svn, google-app-engine

I've got a couple of projects where it would be useful to be able to interact with an SVN server from Google App Engine.

- Pull specific files from the SVN (fairly easy, since there is a web interface which I can grab the data off automatically, but how do I authenticate)
- Commit changes to the SVN (this is the really hard/important part)
- Possibly run an SVN server (from an App Engine app, I'm guessing this isn't possible)

I would prefer a python solution, but I can survive with Java if I must.

Comment: Any ideas for the third point, is it possible to actually run a standalone SVN server off appengine? SVNkit (as far as I can see) only interacts with an already existing server

Comment: what the client can, the server can. any conclusion you can't, even more genrally broader sceintific, probably wrong. technically sure, just respect all very illogical crazy poisonous copyrights

Answer (score 4):

you can try using [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) with the java runtime

Comment: Aha! Looks promising, do you know if SVNkit tries to create any sockets (appengine doesn't allow that)?

Comment: probably it uses sockets in order to communicate with the svn repository.. but it is worty trying anyway imho

Answer (score 3):

DryDrop (http://drydrop.binaryage.com/) is a Git based solution you may want to look at for comparison of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hmm, I've never used GIT, I'll have a look into it

Answer (score 1):

You can talk to a svn server(if setup with apache running [mod_dav_svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html)) using the [webdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) protocol. See [apache's implementation details](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/) Problem is that [google appengine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)'s [urlfetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/) system doesn't allow for HTTP request methods other then GET, POST, HEAD, PUT and DELETE. (webdav uses custom request methods like PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, etc..) So at this time you are restricted to just viewing the contents of the svn server.

You can however use google appengine to implement a webdav provider. Have a look at the [gae-webdav](http://code.google.com/p/gae-webdav/) project for more information.